# Question about MOSFET ground connection

Tags: mosfet, ground

[image]

In the circuit above, the sources of the two MOSFETS should be grounded to the same ground as the FET driver as shown in the schematic ?

Comment: If you can't answer that yourself, PLEASE don't build that circuit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the MOSFET source pins, FET driver ground and microcontroller ground are all connected. Otherwise, they wouldn't be able to drive the FETs.

Also, please be careful with that circuit. If anything goes wrong with the thing, it might catch fire or explode when it shorts out the mains. Your microcontroller will be at live voltage, so don't measure anything when it's connected. And don't leave the programming cable plugged in when you try out the circuit, it'll blow up your computer otherwise.